# Flink 1.14.3 - [issue] failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:6123

Tags: devops, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch, sre

We are using 1.14.3 version of flink and when we try to run Job manager, we are getting below exception.

I tried entering
akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname = "127.0.0.1" in flink-conf.yml file and even updated IP with hostname. But didnt help.

````
[flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] 
ERROR akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport - failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:6123, shutting down Netty transport



ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint - Could not start cluster entrypoint StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointException: Failed to initialize the cluster entrypoint StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint


Caused by: java.net.BindException: Could not start actor system on any port in port range 6123```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have an application already running on port 6123?

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes job manager is running on 6123.  but we are not explicitly mentioning akka.remote.transport.netty too use 6123. from where it is picking the config ?

Comment: Config is stored in `conf/flink-conf.yaml`. You can find all the configuration parameters at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/